# HDP: unable to start Phoenix sqlline.py

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I am using Sandbox HDP 2.2

I did a yum install phoenix (version is 4.2)

But when I run these:

```
./sqlline.py localhost:2181
./sqlline.py localhost
./sqlline.py sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181
./sqlline.py sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

I got the error:

```
15/07/03 08:26:31 ERROR client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: 
The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. 
Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch 
with the one configured in the master.
```

I tried to run:

```
./sqlline.py sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181:/hbase-unsecure
```

But it "hangs" - after 20 minutes still no response

I have this in my /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
  <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create links in the directory where `sqlline.py` lives to 2 .xml files that are provided by HBase/Hadoop.

```
$ pwd
/usr/hdp/2.2.8.0-3150/phoenix/bin

$ ll | grep xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Dec 16 13:34 core-site.xml -> /etc/hbase/conf/core-site.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Dec 16 13:34 hbase-site.xml -> /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
```

With those in place and `$JAVA_HOME` and `java` on your `$PATH`, you can now run `sqlline.py`:

```
$ ./sqlline.py localhost:2181/hbase-unsecure
```

Comment: Worked for me on Phoenix 4.4.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify root dir `"/hbase-unsecure"` in the connection string because by default Phoenix is trying to connect to /hbase. Try this:

> ./sqlline.py localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure

Comment: I already tried it but it "hangs" - after 20 minutes there's still no response

Comment: @sophie: Are you sure that HBase is running? Also, make sure hbase-site.xml is present in path of sqlline.py application. Also, you should reduce timeouts in HBase so that it failfast.Refer to this blog: http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com/2012/09/hbase-client-timeouts.html